# what's the meanning of a executable directory in linux?

Tags: permissions

I know, for a file, a executable permission means this file can be load and run as a process.

but what does mean a executable directory ? (set x for a directory in file permission)

Comment: Sorry cannot comment yet. The execute permission - The read permission allows navigation.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission

Comment: Please refer to this link for detailed description and further readings:
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21251/why-do-directories-need-the-executable-x-permission-to-be-opened