# Using ACL to control read and writes by specific groups

Tags: permissions, acl

I'm new to ACL so I'm creating some demo folders, unfortunately it's not working as expected.

The folder `Triangle` belongs to user pyramid in group `triangle`. 
The user `Cube` in group square needs permission to write to the folder `Triangle`.
I used

```
triangle@ubuntu $ setfacl -m g:square:wx Triangle

triangle@ubuntu $ getfacl Triangle
 file: Triangle
  owner: pyramid
  group: triangle
  user::rwx
  group::rwx
  group:circle:r--
  group:square:-wx
  mask::rwx
  other::---
```

but then when `cube` wants to write a file into `Triangle` I get permission denied.

```
cube@ubuntu $ groups cube
cube : cube square

cube@ubuntu $ touch Triangle/NiceYouLetMeWrite.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘Triangle/NiceYouLetMeWrite.txt’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing files in a directory without x-permission?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission)

Comment: You forgot to give execute permissions to the directory. Members of `circle` or `square` can't traverse it to access files within.

Comment: I added it but I still can't write
group:square:-wx

Comment: Write where? You should be able to create files or delete them (i.e., write to the directory). To write to the file, you'll have to use apply the ACL recursively, or use `d:g:sqaure…` for setting default ACLs.

Comment: I'm trying to write to the directory Triangle with cube$ touch Triangle/NiceYouLetMeWrite.txt

Comment: Then I cannot reproduce your problem. It works fine for me. Update your question with any ACL changes you have made.

Comment: I tried again with sphere in circle group and that works as expected !? cube still doesn't work

Comment: I needed to login logout after adding cube to group sqare

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the user is in the correct groups with the

```
groups
```

command.