# Difference between executable directory vs executable files

Tags: permissions, files, directory

Does having an executable permission on a directory mean that the files inside it are executable too even if the files don't explicitly have executable permissions set ?

Comment: No. Execution permission on directores means search permission (for reading file attributes and cd'ing into the directory). To execute a file, you must have execute permission on that file.

Comment: See the [permissions tag wiki](http://askubuntu.com/tags/permissions/info)

Comment: Also relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/251302/135943

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, the executable permission for directories means that you can enter the directory, making it your present working directory using `cd`, and see which files it contains.

It's useful to think of a directory just as a file which is a list of file names.

**Read bit** - If set, you can read this list. If you have a directory named books:

- You can `ls` books and you'll get a list of the files it contains (`-l` won't work however).
- You can use command-line completion i.e. `touch books/bo`+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to get
  `books/bookfile`.
- You cannot make books your working directory, `cd` won't work.

**Write bit** - You can modify this list names on it. You can only do this if the execute bit is also set.

**Execute bit** - You need this permission if you want to:

- Have any access to files within the directory.
- Modify details of the list itself. You can add, rename or delete names on the list, but this also requires write permission on the directory.

Setting the execute bit on a directory does not in any way affect the files themselves, but it does affect your access to them. For instance if you have write and execute access for a directory, you can move, rename and delete files, even if you can't write into the files themselves.

Comment: That explains a lot actually! Now I understand why some directories appear with a colored background overlay on their name in terminal emulator.

Comment: I've added a bit of info about all permissions, thinking of a directory as a folder full of files isn't as useful as thinking of it as a file in itself, which is just a list of files when it comes to permissions.