# I made a folder unreadable after chmod. I can't undo it from terminal?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

On Ubuntu 16.04,

I created a folder and moved some executable files in it. Later, when trying to execute those files from terminal, i got a `permission denied` error. So I checked folder permissions, like this:

```
cd <path/to/the>
ls -l ./folder
```

And got `-rw-rw-r--` for each executable in the folder.

I did

```
sudo chmod ugo-x ./folder
```

(being completely distracted by the environment) and now the folder has the following permissions: `d---------`. From the system GUI, folder appears with a cross in the right lower corner and with a lock on the right upper corner. I can't access it (`This location cannot be displayed`), GUI properties tell me its unreadable.

I did try

```
sudo chmod ugo-rw ./folder
```

from the same terminal I used to screw it up and from a new terminal as well.

I was able to recover using system GUI, but not via command-line. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are changing permissions without understanding permissions. Have you read `man -a chmod`?

Comment: . . . in particular, see [Difference between executable directory vs executable files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/862289/difference-between-executable-directory-vs-executable-files)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using `sudo chmod ugo-rw ./folder` to add read and write permissions? The minus sign you are writing means that you want to remove those permissions, if you want to add them use a plus instead: `sudo chmod ugo+rw ./folder`