# directory has a executable file mode

Tags: bash

I am learning file mode permissions

```
666: for non-executable ordinary files 
777: for executable ordinary files 
777: for directories
```

Reference to the executable mode,
I could understand that a program file has executable mode, but have
no ideas about why a directory also has a 'executable mode`.

I found it make no sense. a directory entry cannot be executed and cannot set all the files within a directory 'executable` by just set their directory.

How to understand a executable directory entry?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/q/862289, https://superuser.com/q/168578

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been covered in a related post on [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21252/85039):

> The execute bit (x) allows the affected user to enter the directory, and access files and directories inside

An example:

```
$ chmod -x test_access/
$ cd test_access/
bash: cd: test_access/: Permission denied
```

This also prevents from creating/removing files:

```
$ rm test_access/new_file 
rm: cannot remove 'test_access/new_file': Permission denied
$ touch test_access/another_file
touch: cannot touch 'test_access/another_file': Permission denied
```

---

The execute permission actually should be called "access" permission, since when there is no `x` bit set on file or directory, it results in `EACCES` error. You can see that when performing `strace bash -c 'cd test_access/`

```
chdir("test_access")                    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

On the lower level, this particular permission in [`stat.h` standard Unix library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) is defined as

> S_IXUSR
>
> Execute/search permission, owner.

Where search of course refers to directories. Note that reading what directory contains is covered by the `r` bit in the permissions.  Thus, I can still `ls` the directory, but cannot navigate there if there's no `x` bit but there is `r` bit:

```
$ ls -ld test_access
drw-r--r-- 2 admin admin 4096 Jan  4 15:18 test_access
$ ls test_access
test_file
```

If you look at `strace` output for `rm` and `touch`, you'll soon find out that these commands also use variation of `stat()` and `openat()`  syscalls, which also return EACCES

---

#### Side note on ls

Note that on Debian systems with default `/bin/bash` as user's interactive shell, `ls` is often an alias to `ls --color=auto`. Where that's the case, you will see an error such as this:

```
$ ls test_access 
ls: cannot access 'test_access/test_file': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'test_access/new_file': Permission denied
new_file  test_file

$ ls -l test_access 
ls: cannot access 'test_access/test_file': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'test_access/new_file': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? new_file
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test_file
```

The reason behind that lies in the POSIX definition of `EACCES`:

> [EACCES] Permission bits of the file mode do not permit the requested
>   access, or search permission is denied on a **component of the path
>   prefix**

Specifically, if you run `strace ls --color=auto test_access/` you will see that `ls` attempts to perform `lstat()` system call to determine the directory entry type, which is where the EACCES occurs