# How to find files or folders that are inaccessible to a certain user?

Tags: permissions, find

I am trying to install some package in my Joomla but got an error saying "error trying to delete inaccessible file". I checked with the package developer, they said I need to make sure all files and folders under my Joomla installation is accessible to the web server. 
I was reading some tutorial about `find` command and its `-perm` parameter, but the articles I read didn't mention how do I check permission against a particular user; Also they are all about checking files *with* permission but not *without*. 
So how do I find out which file/folder is causing the CMS to throw out this "inaccessible" error?

Answer (score 1):

Access to directory is controlled by `x` - execute - bit in the permissions.  The issue could be due to the user having no executable permissions *as owner* or a group to which user belongs has no [executable permissions set on the directory.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106824/295286)

In order to use `find` for that task, it's sufficient to specify `-user` as the owner of the directory and `-not -executable` flags.:

```
~$ find -type d -user $USER -not -executable
./foo/bar
./test_access
~$ ls -ld ./foo/bar ./test_access
drw-r-xr-- 2 admin admin 4096 Jan 15 03:36 ./foo/bar
drw-r--r-- 2 admin admin 4096 Jan  4 15:38 ./test_access
```

For cases where group part off the permissions is of interest, you could find groups the user belongs to and iterate over them:

```
for i in $(groups $USER | cut -d':' -f2) ; do find -type d -group "$i" -not -executable ; done
```

If neither case turns any potential results, the issue could be due to user not belonging to a group which has access to the directory that gives the issue.

Note also that web servers typically use [`www-data` user/group](https://askubuntu.com/q/873839/295286). You probably want to be checking permissions using that username or group name.