# Folder permission issue

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, directory

Kindly do not consider this as duplicate. 
I have created a folder as root in the directory /tmp/test/ as well as some subfolders too. 
I have changed the permission to read and write for all the users and groups, including the root.

```
$ sudo chmod -R 666 /tmp/test/
```

on issuing the 
`$ ls -l /tmp/test/
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/db': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/sp': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? db
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sp`

I get like this, Here I am unable to create a new file or directory.

```
$ printf 'test' >/tmp/test/sp/test
```

bash: /tmp/test/sp/test: Permission denied
It sounds confusing to me.

Comment: Related: [Accessing files in a directory without x-permission?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission)

Answer (score 5):

Directories require the executable flag, so try `sudo chmod -R 776 /tmp/test`.

Linux/Unix requires the execute bit in order for the user to enter a directory and access its contents, this includes listing what is inside it.  Directory execute flags behave differently than a file's read flag.

Files within can be `666` however.

Comment: Hi @Dorian yours is doing good, but can you give me an option to prevent users on executing a script.

Comment: @Shameerariff To set permissions on only files and not directories, try `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` in the root folder where you want to set the permissions.  DO NOT RUN THIS JUST ANWHERE!  It should find all your files and set read-write permissions and ignore directories.

Comment: thanks for your kind help, But still I can create and execute a script. This folder is for the shared user, I do not want any user to create or execute any kind of script for the security reason. Kindly excuse me,  I am a developer not a SysAdmin, So my approach in this case may be bit idiotic to professional sys admin.

Comment: @Shameerariff No worries!  And I apologise for my original answer.  Please do it again but with `sudo chmod -R 776 /tmp/test`.  This will set read-write-execute(77) for owner and group, and read-write(6) for "everyone else". Now I think the user can write a new file but not make it executable. I don't have a Linux machine to test it myself but that should work.

Comment: Now the permission for the regular user was gone . Now it looks like ls -l /tmp/test
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/db': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/test': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/sp': Permission denied
ls: cannot access '/tmp/test/test.sh': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? db
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? sp
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? test.sh

Comment: @Shameerariff But you were able to run `ls` when the folder permissions were 777?

Comment: Yes I can do anything on 777 but on 776 I am getting the problem

Answer (score 3):

Directory permissions are slightly different than standard file permissions. Instead of read/write/execute like a file, directory permission bits are [as follows](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes#Viewing_permissions):

> `4 (r--)`: The directory's contents can be shown (`ls`)
>   `2 (-w-)`: The directory's contents can be modified (create/delete/rename)
>   `1 (--x)`: The directory can be *accessed* with `cd` or similar.

Note that for directories, the `w` permission will not take effect unless `x` is *also* set.

In your case, your permission is set to bit 6 (`rw-`), which has the following effects:

- You can see the contents of the given folder
- You can not see the metadata for the folder
- You are not permitted to `cd` to that folder or any child folders
- You can not edit the metadata (as `x` is not granted)
- You are not permitted to open any file within this part of the directory tree

To fix this, simply re-add the `x` bit to the file:

```
chmod a+x /path/to/file
```

This is also why the default folder permission is either `0755` or `0775` while files tend to be `0644` or `0664`: folders, unlike files, are effectively useless without `x`.

Comment: I got your option, In-fact your explanation was so good. Is there is any way to prevent the user on executing any BASH scripts.

Comment: @Shameerariff This is a different question, and would  best be asked as one. However, you will want to do this by denying execute to all shell scripts in that folder.

Comment: You are correct, can you give me solution on this comment, Thank you in advance