# users in group can not create files

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

This seems simple but I can not figure it out. I have two user rob and erik both belong to a group called ivdev. ivdev is the group owner of /var/web/www. Neither user can create new files. If I give other permission to write then this will work but defeats the purpose of the group.

```
erik@web1:/var/web$ id -Gn erik
erik adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lxd lpadmin sambashare ivdev

erik@web1:/var/web/www$ id -Gn rob 
rob sudo ssh ivdev

erik@web1:/var/web/www$ touch this
touch: cannot touch 'this': Permission denied

erik@web1:/var/web/www$ su rob
rob@web1:/var/web/www$ touch that
touch: cannot touch 'that': Permission denied

erik@web1:/var/web/www$ cd ..
erik@web1:/var/web$ ls -l
drw-rw-r-x 2 root ivdev 4096 Nov 21 17:22 www
```

Thanks

Comment: And what is the group permissions on `www`?

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody has `x` permission, nobody except root can traverse the directory `www` to access any file inside... See "[Accessing files in a directory without x-permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission)" on this board.

Comment: Making the permissions 775 did the trick. I guess that my understanding of the execute permission was wrong. I thought that a user just needed read/write to work on the files in a folder and an application or server would need execute permission to run the files (py, bash, php, etc).

Comment: @Eman: Permission `x` for files means that they are executable. Permission `x` for directories means that they are traversable (to get to the files inside).