# Why can't I read a file as another user with sudo

Tags: permissions, sudo

I wrote a shell script `.scripter.sh` and wanted to simulate executing the script as another non-root user. I used `sudo -u daemon bash .scripter.sh` to do so, but it says "no permission". I then saw that I cannot read any file as user daemon, and in fact

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~$ touch file
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~$ ll file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 stefan stefan 0 Dez  4 19:01 file
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~$ sudo -u daemon [ -r file ]; echo $?
1
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~$
```

which shows that the user has no read permission, although the permission `-rw-r--r--` indicates that the file is readable by anyone. I hope someone can shed light on this mystery. Thanks

**Edit:** Actually, the following works

```
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~$ cd test/
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~/test$ ll -d .
drwxr-xr-x 2 stefan stefan 4096 Dez  4 19:40 ./
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~/test$ touch file
stefan@stefan-HP-Laptop:~/test$ sudo -u daemon [ -r file ]; echo $?
[sudo] Passwort für stefan: 
0
```

As steeldriver wrote, it has to do with execute permission on the file's parent directory. Indeed, my home directory did not grant any user other than myself any rights.

**Edit2:** It seems you need execute permission on every directory between you and the file you want to read, including your current working directory. I cannot access `~/test/file` as another user from my home folder, but I can do it as another user when I'm in directory `~/test`. This coincides with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission/83791#83791)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior may result from a lack of execute permission on the file's *parent directory*

Ex. given

```
$ ls -ld tests/{,file}
drwxrwxr-x 2 steeldriver steeldriver 4096 Dec  4 13:46 tests/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver  322 Dec  4 13:33 tests/file
```

then

```
$ sudo -u daemon [ -r tests/file ]; echo $?
0
```

but

```
$ chmod o-x tests
$ sudo -u daemon [ -r tests/file ]; echo $?
1
```

You can think of execute permission for a directory as permission to open and traverse the directory contents.

Comment: Yes It appears to be the case but OP did not state that originally!