# user cannot open a specific directory

Tags: permissions, users

I have created a user that I called netbean

Netbean is part of three group:

- netbean (obviously),
- www-data (that is the group the apache server runs under)
- sudo (to have the sudo rights just in case).

I use it to manage the upload of files from my laptop (where i develop) to the webserver.

Issue is that if I try to cd to /var/www/html as netbean i get a permission denied. 
/var/www/html is modded at 665 and is owned by www-data:www-data.

I don't understand why I get a permission denied since it is read and write for www-data and for the users in the www-data group

Comment: Directories need to get executed to enter them. You need 775.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directories [need executable permission](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission) to be able to enter them.
Use `775` instead of `665`.

```bsh
mkdir dir
$ stat -c %a dir
755
$ cd dir #this works
$ cd ..
$ chmod 655 dir
$ cd dir
bash: cd: dir: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the permissions of your directory/file, inorder to access/edit it.
If your directory name is 'example',

```
$sudo chmod a+x example
```

If your file name is 'filename.ext' where 'ext' is your extension,

```
$sudo chmod a+x filename.ext
```