# Why I can't read file?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, ls, cat

Please look at output:

```
deploy@li445-201:~$ sudo ls -al /var/log/nginx/
total 152
drw-rw-r--  2 root     adm      4096 Mar 26 16:08 .
drwxrwxr-x 14 root     syslog   4096 Mar 26 06:25 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 Mar 26 16:08 access.log
-rwxrwxrwx  1 www-data adm    108849 Mar 26 06:10 access.log.1
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data adm     14206 Mar 25 06:17 access.log.2.gz
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data adm     14067 Mar 24 05:31 access.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 Mar 26 16:08 error.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 www-data adm      2522 Mar 24 17:13 error.log.1
```

I try to read log file by deploy user:

```
deploy@li445-201:~$ cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.1
cat: /var/log/nginx/access.log.1: Permission denied
```

Why I can't read log file? I've set even 777 permission on it

Comment: See [Accessing files in a directory without x-permission?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission)

Answer (score 0):

The file's permissions show that any user should be able to read, write or execute the file.  The directory in which this file is located, however, restricts this access.

```
drw-rw-r--  2 root     adm      4096 Mar 26 16:08 .
# ^ /var/log/nginx 'bad'
drwxrwxr-x 14 root     syslog   4096 Mar 26 06:25 ..
# ^ /var/log 'good'
```

In order for a user to be able to list the files in a directory, you need read and execute privileges.  There is a good explanation of why you need the execute bit [that you can read about here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83788/accessing-files-in-a-directory-without-x-permission).  You need to be able to access the inodes, which is where the requirement originates.  I always thought you could read the file but not list the directory, but it seems you need the execute bit to read files in most situations.

And this directory-based restriction goes all the way up to `/`.  This is why a 777 file in your `/home/$USER` directory can't be accessed by another user, because your home directory has no read nor execute privileges for 'other'.